# jquery stop submit propogation from change event

Tags: jquery, forms, event-handling

I have a small form. I'd like to validate the input on the change event and also on the submit event. In this case, for validity I'm checking the number inputted is greater than a minimum allowable. If the input is below the minimum the input should be changed to the minimum. (Or if this is bad UI let me know)

However, I am finding that if someone enters text in the input and then clicks submit, or presses enter the change event fires first. So the input is getting changed automatically on the change event and then when it gets to the submit event, the form passes its validation and is submitted.

Instead, what I'd like is to somehow stop the submission so the user has to at least acknowledge the minimum number is acceptable (probably show an error) before re-submitting. Is this possible?

```
<form data-minimum="10" >
   <input type="number" value="10"/>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

$('input').change(function(){
   if( parseFloat( $(this).val() ) < parseFloat( $('form').data('minimum') ) ){
     $(this).val( $('form').data('minimum') );
     alert('whoa... error');
     // somehow stop submit!
   }
});

$('form').submit(function(){
   if( parseFloat( $('input').val() ) < parseFloat( $('form').data('minimum') ) ){
       return false;
   }
});
```

I've created a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fu6VR/1/

If you enter 5 and press enter it gets submitted, because of the correction caused in the change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In form submit event `this` refers to form, thus you have to use `$('input')`. Use `.val()` instead of `.value()`

```
$('input').change(function () {
    if (parseFloat($(this).val()) < parseFloat($('form').data('minimum'))) {
        $(this).val($('form').data('minimum'));
        alert('whoa... error');
    }
});
$('form').submit(function (event) {
    if (parseFloat($('input').val()) < parseFloat($(this).data('minimum'))) {
        event.preventdefault(); //I prefer
        //return false;
    }
});
```

### EDIT

You can use `.data()` and custom attribute to store valid/invalid details

```
$('input').change(function () {
    if (parseFloat($(this).val()) < parseFloat($('form').data('minimum'))) {
        $(this).val($('form').data('minimum'));
        $(this).data('invalid', 'invalid'); 
        console.log('error');
        // somehow stop submit!
    }else{
        $(this).data('invalid','');
    }
});

$('form').submit(function () {
    var $input = $('input');
    console.log($input.data('invalid'));
    if ($input.data('invalid') == 'invalid' || parseFloat($input.val()) < parseFloat($('form').data('minimum'))) {
        console.log('not submited');
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log('submitted');
    }
});
```

Comment: The code is a very simplified version of what I am doing so it had a few syntax errors in it. However, resolving those doesn't resolve my original question of how to stop the submit from the change event. I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fu6VR/1/) that exemplifies the problem

Comment: @helgatheviking, __Now you are facing logical error.__ Tell me if I enter `101`, your change event will fire and set its value to `10`. Now you click on submit form. The condition `10 < 10` is false thus your form is submitted

Comment: If you enter 101, that is greater than 10 so the change event doesn't change the value and the form is submitted. There's no form handling in the fiddle so it just reloads and gets reset to 10, but you can see in the console that it was submitted and none of the "error" messages are triggered.

Comment: Enter 6, press enter. You can see in the console that the change event is fired and that `6<10` so the input value is changed to 10, so then it passes validation in the submit event and the form is submitted. It's that second part that I want to "pause".

Comment: YES! The data attribute is apparently what I was missing. Can you edit so I can accept?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this one. Cheers.